# Is it possible to send multiple file requests at the same time in PHP?

Tags: php, asynchronous, file-get-contents

I am building an application which makes several page requests using PHP (15 calls for instance). It is important that I have the information from all of these pages before I continue with the rest of my application.

Currently I have a setup to the following effect:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
  $var = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
  $array[i] = $var;
}
```

I then use the array for the rest of my application.

The problem i'm having is that obviously 15 executions of file_get_contents takes a long time, and I was wondering if there is a way in PHP to send off 15 page content requests at the same time, and then continue with the application when all 15 results have been obtained?

Comment: Have a look at `curl_multi_init`.

Comment: Looks good to me, hopefully this will have the desired affect!